# How to insert numbers/text in a textview input?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I want to insert a calculation in a text view for my mathematics game.
I'm in a bit of a problem here, because I don't know what to do.

I tried to create an array that already has some calculations, so when the user clicks the button, it randomly appears a calculation in the text view.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var numArray = ["10/2", "5x5", "12-22", "5-6", "20-70"];
var Question = document.getElementById("textQuestion");

function rollDice(){
    document.form.textQuestion.value = numArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * numArray.length)];
        }
</script>

<form>
    <input type="textview" id="textQuestion">   
    <br>
    <textarea id="textAnswer" form="post" placeholder="Answer"></textarea>
    </form>
    <input type="button" name="start" onclick="">
</body>
```

I expected to have the text view with one calculation so then the user can answer the results, but I have this error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textQuestion' of undefined

Comment: `document.forms[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the first `<form>` element by using `document.forms[0]`. `document.form` doesn't exist (hence the `undefined` error), it's `document.form`***`s`***, and since it's a HTMLCollection, even if it's only got one element, you still need to get that first element.

```
document.forms[0].textQuestion.value = ...
```